# Reorder of cell in Collection View in Swift

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4

I'm using a collection view, inside a cell there is an image view. The images are coming from gallery, now i'm trying to reorder my images. Suppose when i move my image at index 1 to index 0 it moves fine but the issue is that my image in an imageview does not go original which was at index 1, it is changed to an image which is placed at index 0. I have tried this code,

```
 longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
    uploadDocCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
 @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        switch(gesture.state) {

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = self.uploadDocCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.uploadDocCollectionView)) else {
        break

        }
        uploadDocCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
            uploadDocCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
        uploadDocCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
        uploadDocCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()


       }
}
```

In my collection these are the function i have called,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Starting Index: \(sourceIndexPath.item)")
    print("Ending Index: \(destinationIndexPath.item)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image at selected index and insert to the destination index of the same array

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) { 

    let image = arrayOfImages[sourceIndexPath.row] 

    arrayOfImages.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    arrayOfImages.insert(image, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    collectionView.reloadData() 
}
```